# Writing dataframe via sql query (pyodbc): pyodbc.Error: ('HY004', '[HY004])

Tags: sql, python-3.x, hive, pyodbc, impala

I'd like to parse a dataframe to two pre-define columns in an sql table. The schema in sql is:

```
abc(varchar(255))
def(varchar(255))
```

With a dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [False, False],
        [True, True],

    ],
    columns=["ABC", "DEF"],
)
```

And the sql query is like so:

```
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    string = "INSERT INTO {0}.{1}(abc, def) VALUES (?,?)".format(db, table)
    cursor.execute(string, (df["ABC"]), (df["DEF"]))
    cursor.commit()
```

So that the query (string) looks like so:

```
'INSERT INTO my_table(abc, def) VALUES (?,?)'
```

This creates the following error message:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Cloudera][ODBC] (11320) SQL type not supported. (11320) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

So I try using a direct query (not via Python) in the Impala editor, on the following:

```
'INSERT INTO my_table(abc, def) VALUES ('Hey','Hi');'
```

And produces this error message:

```
AnalysisException: Possible loss of precision for target table 'my_table'. Expression ''hey'' (type: `STRING) would need to be cast to VARCHAR(255) for column 'abc'`
```

How come I cannot even insert into my table simple strings, like "Hi"? Is my schema set up correctly or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STRING` type in Impala has a size limit of 2GB.
`VARCHAR`'s length is whatever you define it to be, but not more than 64KB.
Thus there is a potential of data loss if you implicitly convert one into another.

By default, literals are treated as type `STRING`. So, in order to insert a literal into `VARCHAR` field you need to `CAST` it appropriately.

```
INSERT INTO my_table(abc, def) VALUES (CAST('Hey' AS VARCHAR(255)),CAST('Hi' AS VARCHAR(255)));
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work, i just have a new error message (pyodbc.Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Cloudera][ODBC] (11320) SQL type not supported. (11320) (SQLBindParameter)')) related to the placeholder. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Could you try `CAST(? AS VARCHAR(255))` there as well?

Comment: In your python sample, won't  `df["ABC"]` be of type Column? (sorry, not a python fan or expert.) Column type is indeed not supported by Impala ODBC, and you either need to find a way to convert it to string or loop through the dataframe rows and insert them one-by-one, depending on what you're really after.

Comment: right, it's not type Column but a Series, and I can't parse this, it seems. Looks like I'll have to loop through which is a bit annoying as a sweeping insert would be far more efficient. Thanks again.